# How can I make sure my PSI Code executes after a certain event..e.g, creating of a new project

Tags: psi

I am very new to PSI, and I would like to automate a task that happens after the user creates a project..basically , after he clicks, projects-->New--> (then chooses a template/for his project)

How can we create the event handler , and trigger this action..
Thanks a lot ! ^^
Any kind of hint/help would be much appreciated

Julia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using server event handlers will help you in this. You can use "ProjectCreated" or "ProjectCreating" event handlers.
check the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615466(v=office.14).aspx